# how to tell which pods are in a specific priority class?

Tags: kubernetes, pod-priority

Very basic question here: once I have created a priority-class, how do I query which pods are associated with / are in that priority class?

```
kubectl describe priorityclass <name>
```

gives details about the priority class itself

And I can get the details of the individual pod via:

```
kubectl get pod <name> -o yaml
```

But how do I query all pods that are in a particular priority class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will do it:

```
kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath='{.items[?(@.spec.priorityClassName=="highpriority")].metadata.name}{"\n"}'
```

Change `highpriority` with whatever label you are using for your priority.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I was looking for a native query interface for priority class, but your method definitely works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 12):

This will do it:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,PRIORITY:.spec.priorityClassName,VALUE:.spec.priority
```

You can change the namespace for specific one by replacing `--all-namespaces` with `--namespace=<your_namespace>`.

**TIP: You can see what columns are available with -o yaml, for example:**

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o yaml | grep -i priority
```